# NHibernate (and Fluent): Possible to prevent a specific table from being created via SchemaExport.Create?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using Fluent NHibernate (and I'm a newbie).  I have mapped a read-only table that already exists in the database (it's actually a view in the db).  In addition, I have mapped new classes for which I want to create tables using SchemaExport.Create().

In my fluent mapping, I have specified "ReadOnly()" to mark the view as immutable.  However, when I execute SchemaExport.Create(), it still tries to create the table so I get the error "There is already an object named 'vw_Existing'".

*Is there a way to prevent NHibernate from trying to create that specific table?*

I supposed I could export and modify the sql (SetOutputFile), but it would be nice to use SchemaExport.Create().

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for

```
SchemaAction.None();
```